# how to configure scons for Visual Studio 2017 (RC)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, scons, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to get scons configures to use a VS2017RC environment for my build.

It works in the VS2017 command prompt when I define the compiler and linker manually:

```
CC = '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Professional\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.10.24728\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe"'
CXX = '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Professional\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.10.24728\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe"'
LINK = '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Professional\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.10.24728\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\link.exe"'
```

But this does *not* work in the basic command promt.

1) Do you have a working configuration for the standard windows command prompt?

2) It seems that scons can't find the basic include files, since I get the following error:

```
fatal error C1083: File (Include) can't be opened: "stdio.h": No such file or directory
```

Where do I specify those includes?

Comment: Here's the mail thread on this: https://pairlist4.pair.net/pipermail/scons-users/2017-January/005607.html

Answer (score 0):

Likely this issue has long been resolved, but if not.

Please try SCons 4.4.0 with python 3.6+.

It should now find your Visual Studio 2017 install automatically.
No need to explicitly setup CXX, CC, etc..